# How to setup a script that automatically clones the DB every 2 hours?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm planning to build a system that will have 30+ tables and 100+ million rows in a few of those. Going to use MySQL - InnoDB (any better alternative for this?)

My scripts are going to add a couple of hundreds of thousands of clicks to the database every day. On the other hand, I'd like to do heavy database queries during the day as well.

What I came us with is to have two different servers. Server A would take all the clicks and store them and Server B would work on retrieving the results.

Question A: Is this the right approach to do? Question B: Is it possible to set up a script that's cloning the database over from Server A to Server B - so the data is semi-up to date?

Edit: LEMP stack

Comment: [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) stack, I presume?

Comment: You should not do this via a massive batch process. MySQL has built-in replication abilities. You want a slave-master setup.

Comment: @EdCottrell Perfect, thanks, that's what I was looking for. Please make an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Radical_Activity Done! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do this via a batch process that runs a large update every so often. Instead, use MySQL’s built-in replication features.

In particular, use a master-slave configuration. This allows you to keep multiple servers current in (essentially) real-time, while splitting reads (fast) from writes (slow) to get maximum performance.